# SQL - Deleting duplicate columns only if another column matches

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table (TBL_VIDEO) with duplicate column entries in "TIMESTAMP", and I want to remove them **only if the "CAMERA" number matches.**

BEFORE:

```
ANALYSIS_ID | TIMESTAMP | EMOTION | CAMERA
-------------------------------------------    
 1          | 5         | HAPPY   | 1
 2          | 10        | SAD     | 1
 3          | 10        | SAD     | 1
 4          | 5         | HAPPY   | 2
 5          | 15        | ANGRY   | 2
 6          | 15        | HAPPY   | 2
```

AFTER:

```
ANALYSIS_ID | TIMESTAMP | EMOTION | CAMERA
-------------------------------------------    
 1          | 5         | HAPPY   | 1
 2          | 10        | SAD     | 1
 4          | 5         | HAPPY   | 2
 5          | 15        | ANGRY   | 2
```

I have attempted this statement but the columns wouldn't delete accordingly. I appreciate all the help to produce a correct SQL statement. Thanks in advance!

```
delete y
from TBL_VIDEO y 
where exists (select 1 from TBL_VIDEO y2 where y.TIMESTAMP = y2.TIMESTAMP and y2.ANALYSIS_ID < y.ANALYSIS_ID, y.CAMERA = y.CAMERA, y2.CAMERA = y2.CAMERA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution :

```
delete f1 from yourtable f1
where exists 
(
  select * from yourtable f2
  where f2.TIMESTAMP=f1.TIMESTAMP and f2.CAMERA=f1.CAMERA and f1.ANALYSIS_ID>f2.ANALYSIS_ID
)
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you!

Comment: you'r welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
delete f2 from (
select row_number() over(partition by TIMESTAMP, CAMERA order by ANALYSIS_ID) rang
from yourtable f1
) f2 where f2.rang>1
```

Comment: +1 This will work. But just a small remark. Adding the fields in the sub-query is handy if you want to replace that `delete f2` by a `select *` to test what will be deleted. But those are actually not required for the delete. Just the `rang` alone would be enough.

Comment: exactly, i remove that ;)

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number` and find the duplicate and delete them

```
delete from
(select *,row_number() over(partition by TIMESTAMP,CAMERA order by ANALYSIS_ID) as rn from TBL_VIDEO
) t1 where rn>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte
AS
(
    select ANALYSIS_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by TIMESTAMP, CAMERA order by ANALYSIS_ID) rnk
)

DELETE FROM cte WHERE cte.rnk > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `subquery` :

```
select v.*
from tbl_video v
where analysis_id = (select min(v1.analysis_id)
                     from tbl_video v1
                     where v1.timestamp = v.timestamp and
                           v1.camera = v.camera 
                    );
```

However, analytical function with `top (1) with ties` clause also useful :

```
select top (1) with ties v.*
from tbl_video v
order by row_number() over (partition by v.timestamp, v.camera order by v.analysis_id);
```

So, your `delete` version would be :

```
delete v    
from tbl_video v
where analysis_id = (select min(v1.analysis_id)
                     from tbl_video v1
                     where v1.timestamp = v.timestamp and
                           v1.camera = v.camera 
                    );
```